# Are the adjoint and co-adjoint representations isomorphic?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex Lie algebra. Then, we have two canonical representations of $\mathfrak{g}$, namely, the adjoint representation on $\mathfrak{g}$ and the coadjoint representation on $\mathfrak{g}^*$.

> **Question.** Are $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ isomorphic as $\mathfrak{g}$-representations?

We know that the answer is 'yes' if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, since we can use the Killing form to produce an isomorphism.

But this is also true for some non-semisimple Lie algebras. For instance if $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{C}\langle x,y\rangle$ with $[x,y]=x$, then the unique skew-symmetric bilinear form $\omega$ with $\omega(x,y)=1$ is $\mathrm{ad}$-invariant and hence produces an isomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}^*$.

Hence, we could also ask:

> **Question.** Are there conditions on $\mathfrak{g}$ which imply that $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ are isomorphic as $\mathfrak{g}$-representations, and which include both semisimple Lie algebras and the example $\mathbb{C}\langle x,y\rangle$ above?

Comment: If the Lie algebra has a nondegenerate invariant symmetric bilinear form, then the adjoint module is isomorphic to the coadjoint module. See also "quadrable" in Yves paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3895.pdf).